# classic asp application variables in if...then...else statement

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

If I store a variable in the global asa `Application("emergency") = "Emergency"` I can echo "Emergency" by writing `<% = Application("emergency") %>`. How can I do that in an If... Then ... Else statement?

The code that I'm working on ...

```
<% If date()<= <= #3/29/2017# Then response.write("<div style=""margin:30px 0 0""><!-- #INCLUDE FILE=""file.asp"" --></div>") Else response.write(" = Application("emergency") ") %>
```

produces an error. Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It produces an error because this is not a valid string:

```
" = Application("emergency") "
```

Notice the quotes within quotes.

Instead of trying to put code in a string, just call the code:

```
response.write(Application("emergency"))
```

Comment: Okay, that works but what if I want to put that as the href of an anchor. e.g. `response.write("<a href=""Application("emergency")"">link</a>")` has some syntax error but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @user5753132: Then you'd do exactly that.  What's preventing you from doing that?  The server-side code isn't concerned with what HTML strings you print, it's all strings to VB.  Just concatenate the HTML you want before and after that value.

Comment: @user5753132: Yes, the example you just edited into your comment is a syntax error for *exactly the same reason* as the original.  Don't try to put code *in strings*.  The call to `Application("emergency")` itself results in a string.  Just concatenate that with your other string values.